# Fine Grained ACLs For Mercurial On Own Server

Tags: mercurial

We are planning to switch from SVN to a DVCS, probably mercurial. To collaborate, we'd like to still have a central server though. Currently, we use `AuthzSVNAccessFile` for ACLs and authentication to our central SVN server.

In the ACL file, we granted read/write access to groups/users to complete repositories or only subdirectories similar to that example (however for many repositories):

```
[repo:/foo]
bob = rw

[repo:/bar]
alice = rw

[repo:/common]
@repo-clients = r
```

The question is: what is the mercurial way of granting access with such fine-grained ACLs? Which HTTPS based server solution should we use? We'd like to have the ACL configuration for all repositories in one common file. Furthermore, we don't want to use SSH-key authentication mechanisms to keep the hurdle to use collaboration over our server low also for non-tech teams.

Comment: We've now developed our own hgadmin-tool, see https://bitbucket.org/JakobKrainz/hgadmin/overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the mercurial way of granting access with such fine-grained ACLs?

[ACL Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension)

> Which HTTPS based server solution should we use?

Any, while recommended shell for ACL is [hg-ssh](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SharedSSH#head-479a09967fe00153f64bf5fa08ae0b5ede15c388)

> We'd like to have the ACL configuration for all repositories in one common file.

All ACL extension settings have to be confugured in hgrc

> Furthermore, we don't want to use SSH-key authentication mechanisms to keep the hurdle to use collaboration over our server low

Rhodecode is nice, if you can run it

Puttyget+Pageant (for Win-sude) **is** usable for ordinary users (tested), but: ACL is protocol-agnostic, thus you can use http|https (and will be ready to possible additional headache around https)

Comment: ACL extension settings can be in a single central hgrc file such as /etc/mercurial/hgrc.  They don't have to be in each repo's .hg/hgrc.

Comment: One settings for different repos in one place doesn't seem nice -[acl.*.branches] operates by branch-names, which can intersect in independent repos

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea, just that the original requirements included a single point of config and that it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a [RHodeCode](http://www.rhodecode.org) which has user groups, and repository groups and a nice UI for the server.

Comment: rhodecode doesn't do per-directory permissions, which I think was a requirement above.