# Is there a way to get users and groups for mercurial repository from remote

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-server, mercurial-api

Is there a way to get users and groups for mercurial repository from remote? I am a newbie to mercurial world and not being able to get much details on this.

I wish to get and set the groups and users on a repository from remote (application).

The mercurial server is using acl extension.

Comment: And what are 'users and groups' in terms of a VCS? Access rights to a ressource (here the VCS) are a local configuration which are not exactly related to the VCS itself. What information are made public about that is a question about the interfaces offered (ssh, web interfaces like kallithea, redmine...). Mercurial itself has no access control (though there's one plug-in, the aclextension)

Comment: @planetmaker, the server in question is using acl extension.

Comment: There is nothing to "set". You're doing it wrong.

Comment: @DanMan, I know there is something wrong. But, how should I do if I wish to set up the authorization from remote (as automation might be)?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the users that have worked on the current repo with

```
hg log --template "{author}\n"
```

However, this will return many duplicates, so you may want to pipe to `uniq`:

```
hg log --template "{author}\n" | uniq
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish to get and as well set groups and users from a remote (application).

Answer (score 1):

Any type of access restrictions like group permissions would have to be installed outside of Mercurial, like setting up a password-protected network share on which you put the main repository or something.

For ACL look here: [Fine Grained ACLs For Mercurial On Own Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103499/fine-grained-acls-for-mercurial-on-own-server) or here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mercurial+acl

And then there's the manual: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories and https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AuthorizingUsers